# String Array only returns one string in android

Tags: java, android, string, random

I'm trying to display a string inside a textView object.
currently I'm only getting the first string in the string array.

```
   public void onClick(View v) {
        Resources res = getResources();
        String[] hintsStr = res.getStringArray(R.array.hints);
        TextView hintShow = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.hintShow);
        int rndInd = (int) Math.random()*5;
        //hintShow.setText(rndInd);
        hintShow.setText(hintsStr[rndInd]);
        //System.out.print(rndInd);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to generate your random numbers.-

```
Random rand = new Random();
int rndInd = rand.nextInt(5); // Will get a rand number between 0 and 4
```

Also, you should instantiate rand object just once, as an instance variable outside `onClick` method.

Answer (score 1):

You are casting the result of Math.rand() to int so the result is always 0, you can do `int rndInd = (int)(Math.random()*5);` or even better use the solution that ssantos suggested

Answer (score 0):

First initialize Random Class and then get value,see below code

```
Randon random=new Random();
int value = random.nextInt(10);
```

It will work for sure.